# Mapping a pointer to an array of structures in JNA

Tags: java, c, jna

I would like to get an array from a pointer like this :

```
PointerByReference buf=new PointerByReference();
IntByReference len=new IntByReference(); 

myLib.getPoints(buf,len);

Pointer p=buf.getValue();
JNAPoint jnaPoint=new JNAPoint(p);
JNAPoint[] points=(JNAPoint[])jnaPoint.toArray(len.getValue());
```

The prototype of the function is :
    void __declspec (dllexport) getPoints(point** tab,int* len);

The structure is :
    typedef struct _point
    {
        double x;
        double y;
    } point;

But, when I want to read the array "points", the values are wrong.

Is there a mistake ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you call `Structure.read()` in your `JNAPoint(Pointer)` constructor?  JNA will do so automatically in the `toArray()` call, but you are responsible for calling it for the first element.